# VueJS submit are delayed resulting in wrong data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rendering, lifecycle

I have a method in my Vue Instance which updates and removes a value from my database. When the method is submitted the values are updated correctly, but I need to do a refresh before the values are removed from the frontend. Below are my method:

```
 async winBet(id, amount, bet) {
      try {
        this.bet.id = id
        this.bet.amount = amount
        this.bet.bet = bet
        await this.$http.post("/user/winBet", this.bet);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },


<form @submit="winBet(value._id, value.amount, value.bet)">
  <button type="submit">Won</button>
</form>
```

I render the list, which after the submit should be not contain the submitted element, the following way

```
<ul v-for="value in pendingBets">
  <li>Bet: {{value}}</li>
</ul>

________________________________________________________________
mounted() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/user/getUser', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': this.myval.email
      }),
    })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
      this.pendingBets = data[0].allBets
    }.bind(this));
    }
```

For some reason I need to do a refresh before the value is removed from "pendingBets". Sometimes it works and sometimes I have to do the refresh. I'm still new to Vue so hope someone can ping me in the right direction here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thats becks mounted() loads only once

Comment: I suggest you to rehit the api as soon as you submit...

Comment: Also what I thought. I just struggle finding the best/correct way to rehit the api call after submit. Do you have any suggestions to best practice on this? I assume rehit the api inside the submit method, is not best practice.

Comment: Yes please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Re-hit the api as soon as you hit submit, I have defined a generic function called getData inside the methods which is being reused

```
methods: {
async winBet(id, amount, bet) {
      try {
        this.bet.id = id
        this.bet.amount = amount
        this.bet.bet = bet
        await this.$http.post("/user/winBet", this.bet);
        await this.getData();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
   async getData() {
    await fetch('http://localhost:4000/user/getUser', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'email': this.myval.email
      }),
    })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function (data) {
      this.pendingBets = data[0].allBets
    }.bind(this));
   }
}
```

and your

```
mounted() {
 this.getData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. Unfortunatly, It's still the same result...

Comment: what is happening, is it showing any error?

Comment: No, not throwing any errors. But the result is it same in the sense, that I still need to refresh the page for the data to be loaded correctly after submit.

Comment: there was a typo in the code on line no 8

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to implement a window.location.reload() with a short setInterval.